# could not detect lines in opencv because of aliasing?

Tags: opencv

I used the opencv to analyze multiple choice scanner, but first of all I have to make the image black & white (binarization) and Use hough transform to find the lines in the image.

This is the original image [image: The original image]
// smooth the image

```
Mat img = imread(path,1);
if(img.empty()){
   cout << "no picture shown" <<endl;      
}   
cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
Size size(3,3);
GaussianBlur(img,another,size,0);
adaptiveThreshold(another,another,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);
bitwise_not(another,another);
```

// find lines with houghline

```
   vector<Vec4i> lines; 
   HoughLinesP(img,lines,1,CV_PI/180,80,400,10);
   cout << "line size : " << lines.size() << endl;
```

However the problem is I still could not find any line, here is the processed image
[image: The processed image].

From the resulted image, I think the problem is because of aliasing on the edge, is it? does it affect the houghline, and how can I remove the aliasing?

Comment: Maybe your problem is the `minLineLength`? Are you sure the lines in your image are longer than 400 px? I'd recommend playing a little with the parameters to see what you'll get..

Comment: true, thanks Mahm00d. But it is not easy to determine the proper minLineLength parameter, if this is too large, there is no line, if there is too small, there are many lines than expected

Comment: If you want to find only 4 long lines you may set minLineLength to 0.8*imageWidth, if you want short lines too(but still not to many lines) try to set it for about 0.05-0.2 of image width. Note that in the end you are looking for circles you may try houghCircles function.

Answer (score 0):

If this image is the same size here as when you uploaded it: Your entire image is only 405x405, so looking for a line 400 pixels long is a bit much. You could easily get away with the min being 100 - but I wouldn't go above 350 if all you want are the exterior 4 lines making the square.